# Keep router interfaces isolated

Tags: cisco, router, interface

Have a Cisco Router 2811 with a HWIC that gives it an extra port so I have 3 Ethernet ports. Have it configured like this:

FA0/0- 192.168.1.1
FA0/1- 192.168.10.1
FA1/0- 10.0.0.1 (outside)

All that works fine except the .1 and .10 networks can talk and ping each other. Is there anyway to separate them so they can't see the other one but both can still access the internet?

Comment: The interfaces being able to communicate with each other and hosts connected to those interfaces being able to communicate with each other are two different things. Have you checked the latter? My guess is that your real concern is that you don't want hosts connected to those interfaces to be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: Yea I want to isolate the hosts from the .1 interface so they cannot talk to hosts on the .15 interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ACL that blocks the traffic. Something along those lines (will need to be more tailored):

```
 ip access-list extended AL-INSIDE-1  
  deny ip 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0  
  permit ip 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 any

 ip access-list extended AL-INSIDE-10  
  deny ip 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0  
  permit ip 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 any

 int fa0/0  
  ip access-group AL-INSIDE-1 in

 int fa0/1
  ip access-group AL-INSIDE-10 in
```

May need to tweak this - I don't know all the details of your setup but that should get you going pretty well.

Comment: Yea I figured acl was the best way just not sure how to do that one.