# Inter-VLAN routing: multiple VLANs, only one should be accessible to all. Makes sense?

Tags: routing, vlan, subnet

I am trying to segment our company's network. My main goal is to have many small broadcast domains instead of a gigantic one, so I thought of assigning one VLAN per department.

However, we have many printers and a centralized file server that should be accessible to any device within the company. So, I imagine these services should belong in a separate VLAN which, in turn, would communicate with department VLANs through L3 addressing.

As we own an L3 Cisco switch, inter-VLAN routing seems to be a valid way to go. But as I am experimenting it, I am noticing that I have to assign an IP address to each VLAN interface (thus allocating each department into its own subnet) and, as soon as I allow `ip routing` on the L3 switch, the devices can ping not only printers or the file server, but also any other device on any other department.

I know the broadcast domain is not the same between one subnet and another, but I thought it would be more secure somehow if those VLANs could not communicate with each other.

That being said, here are my doubts on the subject:

**1)** For the sake of security, is it better to isolate those department VLANs in a way that they can only see the printers/files VLAN (not seeing each other)?

**2)** If so, what is the best way of doing it? The only feasible approach I can think of is to use ACLs, but they do not seem that practical as I would have lots of entries to handle.

Comment: Maybe you need a firewall?

Comment: Here's a phrase I like to use for questions like this: **Tilting at windmills.** You're implementing VLAN's based on vague ideas about "security" and "broadcast domains". Do you have a real problem that can be solved with VLAN's or are you simply doing this because you think you should or because someone told you that you should or because you read somewhere that you should?

Comment: I think broadcast domains hardly to be considered a vague idea. Disallowing clients to reach each other is quite hard these days that users can simply decide to use cloud services to solve their problem, it takes quite a bit of thought beyond vlans. Worst case one creates s security problem where there was none.

Comment: @Marki - to block traffic between department can be done easily with the L3 switch he already has - no need for a firewall here.

Comment: @joeqwerty I didn't go into much detail because I was afraid my question would be too extensive; maybe I oversimplified it, I don't know. Basically, I want to divide the network because of three things: 1) Limiting scope - as far as possible, issues from one department should not propagate to other departments. 2) Better tracking - just by looking at the address of a host, I could locate it. 3) Performance - right now, broadcast storms may compromise our entire network. I'm not tied to VLANs or subnetting, they were just the possible solution I could think of. Feel free to give any ideas.

Comment: @Renato - if you have 20-50 hosts, then it's probably not worth too much trouble, but if you have 200+ hosts, then by all means, break your broadcast domain with VLAN for each area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Depends on your security requirements. If your requirements are that the user PC should only be able to communicate with servers/printers, and not between PCs, then yes, you should have ACLs on the Interface VLAN to block traffic as desired. What is the most secure - well blocking everything but what is really needed is the most secure.

2) To do this you simply implement ACLs and apply the ACLs to the Interface VLAN. Since you're trying to allow PCs to Servers/Printers, your ACLs should be simple... something along the lines of:

assuming your subnets are all 10.0.0.0 and your Servers/Printers are in 10.1.1.0/24:

```
permit ip 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255
deny ip any any log
```

That is obviously a simple version, you'll need to tweak from there to obtain the exact result desired. With this example, you can apply that to all your PC VLAN Interfaces as it is written in a generic way that will work for all your VLANs.

You can find another example of this in another question which I answered last week: [Keep router interfaces isolated](https://serverfault.com/questions/571163/keep-router-interfaces-isolated)

Comment: Is your proposal to solve all internet access through proxies?

Comment: @ErikE - Not particularly as there were no mention of Internet in the OP question. He is trying to block traffic between departments. But having all Internet traffic through proxy is something I would recommend yes to better control what is allowed out for security reasons - if just to get some logs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The ACL syntax did clarify things a bit. As for the first point, I haven't elaborated security requirements - mostly due to lack of knowledge. What would you say are possible threats of letting all the devices communicate with each other through the network layer? In your opinion, is it worth it to block communication between sections of an organization?

Comment: @Renato - it's hard to say without knowing more the type of business, size of network, other security measures on your machines. But take this example, Virus Infected Machine A starts hitting all your machines through an open RPC connection and spreads... well if you block traffic between your department, you'll at least mitigate this. What if you have security requirements on documents and you find that Joe in Dept A is a wiseass and set himself up to be able to VNC to all other departments... you could block that, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common situation and unfortunately the initial response should not be technical. Inter-Vlan routing is fine if it works for your company. Yes there are possible security and performance issues but do you have the staff to manage the requirements if you lock your systems down?

As long as you have designed your network properly you should be able to secure inter vlan routing and limit the changes necessary after the fact. And just like you said, by securing your vlan you are reducing your security risk, improving performance, and enabling you to put controls in place to track IP's and devices.